# Redirect customer to My Account after complete purchase - Magento

Tags: magento

What I want is simple. Whenever, my customer make a purchase on my website I want him/her to be redirected to "My Account" page.

How can I do that?

I am using Magento 1.4.2

Please explain which files to edit and where to edit with whatever code.

Comment: So you want to avoid the Success page and redirect the Customer to the User account? What would happen if the Customer is a Guest user?

Comment: Hello Barbanet,

Correct. Instead of Success page I want to display User Account page. Same thing will happen if it's a Guest Customer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to pass through the success controller in order to complete the Order.
For example, the successAction into the OnepageController executes some actions to complete the purchase process.
Maybe you can try with an override to that controller (you'll need to do the same with the multishipping controller if you want to use it) to get the redirect to the new destination.
If you don't want to apply an override you an use an observer for the checkout_onepage_controller_success_action event.

Comment: Hello barbanet,

Thanks for your reply. But I am not so technical. Can you please tell me which files to edit?

I am using Magento 1.4 version.

Comment: This kind of modification needs some techniclas knowledge. Take a look to the app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php file.  Into the successAction method you'll what's happen when you reach that page. There you can start to find your modification (but remember that isn't a good practice apply modifications onver core files.